# Update list of dictionaries based on another list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists of dictionaries, one is a list of project identifiers and the other a list of completed project identifiers. I'm looking to add a key to the project identifier list, based on existence in the completed list.

**Current code**

```
>>> projects = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
>>> completes = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]
>>> for complete in completes:
...     for project in projects:
...         if project["id"] == complete["id"]:
...             project["complete"] = 1
...         else:
...             project["complete"] = 0
...
>>> print projects
[{'id': 1, 'complete': 0}, {'id': 2, 'complete': 1}, {'id': 3, 'complete': 0}]
```

**Expected output**

```
[{'id': 1, 'complete': 1}, {'id': 2, 'complete': 1}, {'id': 3, 'complete': 0}]
```

How can I break out of the nested loop once a project has been flagged as complete? Is there another approach I should consider instead of working with the nested loop?

Comment: Why don't you just make a dictionary of projects where the key is the `id` and the value can be the dictionary of information you are using.

Comment: @GWW I'm using the output to write a csv file as input into an ETL process, and wanted to keep the column headings in the dictionary. I guess I could create a separate list of headers and values as you suggest.

Comment: If you are processing a lot of entries it will give a decent performance boost, otherwise it's probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit - fixed (thanks to @sotapme)

Why not something like:

```
cids = [c['id'] for c in completes]
for project in projects:
    project["complete"] = project["id"] in cids
```

This will set `project["complete"]` to `True` or `False`, which I suggest is better. If you really need `1` and `0`, then:

```
    project["complete"] = int(project["id"] in cids)
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me using the OP's data. http://pastiebin.com/?page=p&id=511401d343247

Comment: @sotapme. Thanks for the edit suggestion and the implication there was beauty in my solution. Unfortunately, I'm rejecting it because I prefer to have the list generated outside the loop. It doesn't change and regenerating it isn't good for performance (function over beauty). Also where you suggested `[i  for c in completes for i in c.values()]`, I prefer the simpler equivalent (equivalent in this case, if more keys are added your version might be wrong), `[c['id'] for c in completes]`.

Comment: That's fine. I was just trying to restore some of the original elegance.  It's all good.  Now it's 50% more lines :D

Answer (score 1):

If you store them as a dict of dicts keyed by id versus an array of dicts, it becomes much easier (in my opinion):

```
projects = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
completes = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}]

projects_dict = {}
for p in projects:
    projects_dict[p['id']] = p

completes_dict = {}
for c in completes:
    completes_dict[c['id']] = c

for k in projects_dict.keys():
    projects_dict[k]['complete'] = int(k in completes_dict)
```

Of course instead of looping through completes, just add the 'complete' key wherever it is you create the 'completes' array of dicts.

Comment: Since you require an array of dicts in the end for your CSV output, just use .values() to get the array of dicts you require again.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, but what jimhark is saying is good, except I think you need to say something like

```
for project in projects:
    project['complete'] = project['id'] in (complete['id'] for complete in completes)
```

Edit: He has since changed his answer to be correct

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I skipped a step as @sotapme pointed out, but I've fixed it now.

Comment: Also, I think it's worth it to pull the id list generation out of the loop.

Comment: So do I - I was just changing your original code as little as possible :)